# Problem with calling a php function from javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to make a rating system and need to call a function from the file starating.php and pass there variables - $id (post id) and rating percent. I'm not sure how to call those variables and then afterward refer to them in starating.php This is my code:

```
$( function() {
    var postID = <?php echo $id; ?>;

    var rating = new starRating( { // create first star rating system on page load
        containerId: '$id', // element id in the dom for this star rating system to use
        starWidth: 60, // width of stars
        starHeight: 60, // height of stars
        ratingPercent: '0%', // percentage star system should start 
        canRate: true, // can the user rate this star system?

        user: '$userLoggedIn',

        onRate: function() { // this function runs when a star is clicked on
            //console.log( rating );
            $.ajax({
                url: '../handlers/starating.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data: 'post_id='+postID+'&rating_num='ratingPercent,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(){
                    console.log('works');
                }
            }); 
            //alert('You rated ' + rating.newRating + ' starts' );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Frist, if you want to interact with PHP and JavaScript directly you should make sure that your script is on that .php file it means inside **script tag** not imported.

Now since to display a variable in php we use **echo**, you should replace your code by this one.

```
$( function() {
                            var postID = '<?php echo $id; ?>';

                            var rating = new starRating( { // create first star rating system on page load
                                containerId: '<?php echo $id; ?>', // element id in the dom for this star rating system to use
                                starWidth: 60, // width of stars
                                starHeight: 60, // height of stars
                                ratingPercent: '0%', // percentage star system should start 
                                canRate: true, // can the user rate this star system?

                                user: '<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>',

                                onRate: function() { // this function runs when a star is clicked on
                                    //console.log( rating );
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '../handlers/starating.php', 
                                        type: 'POST', 
                                        data: 'post_id='+postID+'&rating_num='ratingPercent,
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function(){
                                            console.log('works');
                                        }
                                    }); 
                                    //alert('You rated ' + rating.newRating + ' starts' );
                                }
                            } );
                        } );
```

`

Comment: Thanks, but now i get the error VM1158:81 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.domManip (jquery.min.js:3)
    at n.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.success (index.php:152)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: @Bartekgrot Can you post your final code? because it seems as the error is at **line 152 of index.php**

Comment: '$.ajax({
                                                url : "../handlers/starating.php",
                                                data : 'id=' + id + '&rating=' + rating.newRating,
                                                type : "POST"
                                            });'

Comment: now I have a diffrent error: C:\xampp\htdocs\social\includes\classes\Post.php on line 324     this is the starating.php code: ?php
require("../../dbConfig.php");
include("../classes/User.php");
include("../classes/Post.php");

Comment: And the class I'm doing the ajax call in is Post.php

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.

First of all, it is not a good idea to include `php` code directly in the `js` file, for many reasons among them, readability, security etc. These two should be strictly separated and have the `ajax` to control what happens between.

Here is an example:

**JS**

```
function Call_AJAX({do_action,ajax_id,do_success}) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : ajax_url,
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                action : do_action,
                id: ajax_id
            },          
            success : do_success
        });
    };
```

**php**

```
function call_php_function(){           
    $id   = $_POST['id'];       

    //Do something wit the call then return result
    $result = do_something();           
    echo json_encode($result);  
    exit;           
};
```

then you can call this like this in `js`:

```
//Get some sort of result
var result_append = function (data) {
    //Do something with the returned data
    console.log(data.result)
};  

Call_AJAX(
    do_action = 'call_php_function',
    ajax_id = some_ajax_id,
    do_success = result_append);
```

This way, you can call a specific function in `php` (such as `call_php_function()`), then get the rating information. Once you got the result, then send it back via `json_encode`. And you can display them once ajax call is a success. You can implement error handling in both sides. This way that whatever happens in front-end doesn't affect the back-end, visa versa.

Hope this helps.